# How to cross-reference inside of a verbatim (or listings) environment

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, verbatim

I would like to reference other parts of my document (e.g. equations, figures) inside of some source code. Is there an escape sequence such that `\ref` will be parsed instead of printed as a literal \ref?

My minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
This is the pythagorean theorem:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

I can reference it normally: Equation \ref{eq:pyth}.

I can write a code example that won't work:
\begin{verbatim}
# An R function to solve for c.
# See Equation \ref{eq:pyth} for details.
solve.for.c <- function(a,b){
  return( sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
}
\end{verbatim}

And one that works, but is very ugly and hard to maintain: \\
\verb@# An R function to solve for c.@ \\
\verb@# See Equation@ \ref{eq:pyth} \verb@for details.@ \\
\verb@solve.for.c <- function(a,b){@ \\
\verb@solve  return( sqrt(a^2 + b^2))@ \\
\verb@}@ \
How can I do this better?
\end{document}
```

Any thoughts on how to do this better? Is there a simple feature I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not missing simple features; the standard `verbatim` environment doesn't allow for interpreting commands. However, the `fancyvrb` package has this facility:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
This is the pythagorean theorem:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

I can reference it normally: Equation \ref{eq:pyth}.

I can write a code example that will work:
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\[\]]
# An R function to solve for c.
# See Equation \ref[eq:pyth] for details.
solve.for.c <- function(a,b){
  return( sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
}
\end{Verbatim}

And also a \texttt{lstlisting} environment:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R,escapechar=',columns=fullflexible]
# An R function to solve for c.
# See Equation '\ref{eq:pyth}' for details.
solve.for.c <- function(a,b){
  return( sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

For `commandchars` in `Verbatim` you have to specify three characters (escaped with the backslash) that aren't otherwise used in the environment's text. The same for `escapechar` with `lstlisting`. These characters may be chosen "locally".

Take your pick.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you have three handy characters that don't appear in the verbatim text you can use them instead of `\ { }` for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\oldv\@verbatim
\def\@verbatim{\oldv\catcode`\!=0 \catcode`\`=1 \catcode`\'=2 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the pythagorean theorem:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

I can reference it normally: Equation \ref{eq:pyth}.

I can write a code example that won't work:
\begin{verbatim}
# An R function to solve for c.
# See Equation !ref`eq:pyth' for details.
solve.for.c <- function(a,b){
  return( sqrt(a^2 + b^2))
}
\end{verbatim}



How can I do this better?
\end{document}
```